# Set a list in excel to an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list in excel adn I want to make it an array to delete column names that match.  The following works:

```
arrColumnNames = Array("Month", "Day")
```

However I want a dynamic list.  I have also  tried

```
arrColumnNames = Worksheets("List").Range("J2:J35").Value
```

But that crashes excel.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: original post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213697/delete-columns-based-on-a-list

Comment: You can't compare array like that ... you would have to loop through each element

Comment: so I have a loop to go to the end of the list and run the macro once for each element in the list?

Comment: You're confusing yourself. :) Run a loop over each element in list that you want and assign them to an array. However, I'm thinking you can do this without arrays. What are your full conditions? What does `J2:J35` contain and what do you want deleted from there?

Comment: I probably am :p. I havent used VBA in years so I am drinking through a firehose to catch up.. I have a few macros to get to this step. It compiles a list eventually and that list is purely column headers. The remaining list is what columns I want to remain on the main page.

Comment: REmove the `.Value` from your code and it should set arrColumnNames to the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work well enough, without frills.

```
Sub RemoveColumnsWithDiffHeaders()

    Dim MainSht As Worksheet, RefSht As Worksheet
    Dim HeaderList As Range, Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set MainSht = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as needed.
        Set RefSht = .Sheets("Sheet2") 'Modify as needed.
    End With

    Set HeaderList = RefSht.Range("A1:A8") 'Modify as needed.

    For Each Cell In MainSht.Rows(1).Cells
        If Application.CountIf(HeaderList, Cell.Value) = 0 Then
            MainSht.Columns(Cell.Column).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

`HeaderList` contains the list of headers to retain. Modify all other ranges/assignments to suit.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: It seems to get stuck in a loop in the If. Is there a better way to compare values than a Countif returning a 0, and actually matching text? Sorry if the question doesnt even make sense!

Comment: Actually I am going to change the 0 to a 1 and instead of delete copy to another page so I have source data untouched. Without you I couldnt have gotten it. Thansk so much BK.

Comment: ..This is basically identical to my answer on your other question except mine is faster as instead of looping every column in the worksheet, i loop that smaller list or values to copy, and I use the Match function instead of count function.. Also mine is simply more dynamic instead of hard coded as this is.

Comment: Sorry 2140261 I take responsibility for not executing correctly. I will mess around and try it more too!

Answer (score 0):

```
dim arrColumnNames() as variant
redim arrColumnNames (2 to 35, 1 to 1) 'not really needed, but i use it like this to paste data again back to sheet after doing operations, much faster than doint it by reading each cell.
arrColumnNames = Worksheets("List").Range("J2:J35").Value 

'code , calculation on arrColumnNames ...

Worksheets("List").Range("J2:J35").Value = arrColumnNames 'writes back to sheet, 'instantenuously'.

redim arrColumnNames (0,0)
erase arrColumnNames 'i am not sure if need redim but if i understood, the erase function only puts blanks in the data, so the array still take a bit of memory. Whatever, i'm a noob.
```

this code only is usefull(performance) if you work with many cells/rows/big range(...) (over 100 or 1000), or if you want to make arrays ;)