# Run a loop to check columns based on header name, and insert columns if they are missing

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am new to VBA and have been tasked with creating a macro to clean up and save .csv files. So far I have been able to put together the script from other answered questions here on Stack Overflow, but the final piece is eluding me.

So far I can open, check for columns that need to be deleted, delete them, then save as a new file. What I need to do is check if columns are missing and insert them so that the csv files all consistently have the same header row.

For example:

Let's say that all of the necessary columns  have the first row cell values as "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf"

But sometimes the CSV files we receive only go from "Alpha" to "Echo"

I need to check for this and then insert the columns "foxtrot" and "Golf" in their respective order. How would I go about doing this?

It seems like with minor tweaks and a little more code, I can modify my column delete script (which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213842/4292905)) to do this.

```
Dim rngFound As Range
      Dim rngDel As Range
      Dim arrColumnNames() As Variant
      Dim varName As Variant
      Dim strFirst As String

      arrColumnNames = Array("Hotel","India","Julliet")

      For Each varName In arrColumnNames
          Set rngFound = Rows(1).Find(varName, Cells(1, Columns.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
          If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
              strFirst = rngFound.Address
              Do
                  If rngDel Is Nothing Then Set rngDel = rngFound Else Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, rngFound)
                  Set rngFound = Rows(1).Find(varName, rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
              Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
          End If
      Next varName

      If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireColumn.Delete

      Set rngFound = Nothing
      Set rngDel = Nothing
      Erase arrColumnNames
```

But it's a little beyond me as I've never worked with VBA; can someone provide some direction?

Comment: Are the column names sufficiently different that one is not a partial match of any other? What is there is a column that is not in your list?

Comment: Is the order of columns important? - what if all columns are there but in a different order?

Comment: Order is paramount which is why I have to add these empty columns in their respective spots. Also, there is lots of naming similarity in headers although no exact matches. E.g. "Phone1""Phone2" "ContactName" "ContactName2" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put any missing columns off the right side and then sort left-to-right (rather than the typical top-to-bottom). However, I'll assume that your column header labels are not like the nice alphabetic ones you've provided so that means a custom sort and you would have to provide all of the column names for that.

The [Array Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method can quickly determine if you have columns that do not belong however it is a pattern match not an exact match so there is a possibility of false positives. Your own results will depend on the actual names of the columns header labels you use. If this is an inappropriate method then simply loop through each.

```
Sub fixImportColumns()
    Dim c As Long, vCOLs As Variant

    vCOLs = Array("Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", _
                  "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Julliet")

    With Worksheets("myImportedCSV")

        'add non-existent columns from list
        For c = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
            If IsError(Application.Match(vCOLs(c), .Rows(1), 0)) Then _
                .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = vCOLs(c)
        Next c

        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

            'get rid of columns not in list (from right-to-left)
            For c = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                If UBound(Filter(vCOLs, .Cells(1, c), True, vbTextCompare)) < 0 Then _
                    .Columns(c).EntireColumn.Delete
            Next c

            'create a custom list for the sort order
            Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCOLs

            'clear any remembered sort
            .Parent.Sort.SortFields.Clear

            'sort the columns into the correct order
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo, MatchCase:=False, _
                        OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Although not widely used, the [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) can sort blocks of data from lef-to-right and use a custom list as the sort order.

Comment: This seems like it should work. I did some hard value setting to the columns as a stop gap for now due to time constraints, but it will break if anything else changes in the source files. I will test this implementation though when I get a chance. Thank you.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs. At first I thought something was broken and commented to that effect, but realized it was my own issue and deleted that comment. My array is huge, but I have tested on multiple files with consistent results. Thank you very much for your input on this, I don't know how I would get by without this community!

Comment: Looks like I ran into a hiccup. The array filter sorting is now partially sorting alphabetically... Where I have columns with similar names "Contact1" "contact1first" "Contact2" etc it has sorted these and subsequent columns to the right alphabetically, but my first few columns are arranged in the array order. I believe this is the risk you mentioned in it not being an exact match, so I assume I need to change this to the Range.Sort method you mentioned. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble finding information on how to use it with my array. Canyou please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of it (assuming duplicate column names are not permitted):

```
Sub ReorderAddDeleteCols()

    Dim arrCols, x As Long, sht As Worksheet, f As Range, s

    'All the fields you want in the final version (in the order needed)
    arrCols = Array("Col1", "Col5", "Col2", "Col3", "Col6")

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'insert enough columns for the required fields
    sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arrCols) + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    x = 1

    For Each s In arrCols
        Set f = sht.Rows(1).Find(What:=s, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'column found, move to required location
            sht.Columns(f.Column).Cut sht.Cells(1, x)
        Else
            'not found - add header
            sht.Cells(1, x).Value = s
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Next s
    'delete all other remaining columns (100 just an arbitrary value here...)
    sht.Cells(1, x).Resize(1, 100).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: This also looks like it may work for my needs and seems pretty straightforward. I will test in my environment. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I made a mistake with this, but after incorporating your code, I lose all of the data in the rows. I end up with just the header row and nothing else.

Comment: I tested my code and it worked OK.  Are all your headers in row 1?  If you put a breakpoint on the line `sht.Columns(f.Column).Cut sht.Cells(1, x)` does it hit that line?  If not there is some mismatch between the headers in your data and what you're telling it to look for.  If you can share your workbook I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work as standalone to do what you want. You can incorporate into your existing code, or simply add as a separate sub to just do this activity.

It loops through the list backward and adds any missing columns in alphabetical order.

```
Sub AddMissingColumns()

Dim arrColumnList() As String

arrColumnList = Split("Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,Golf", ",")

Dim x As Integer
For x = UBound(arrColumnList) To LBound(arrColumnList) Step -1

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Set rngFound = Sheets("sheet1").Rows(1).Find(arrColumnList(x), lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

        Dim sLastFound As String
        sLastFound = arrColumnList(x)

    Else

        If sLastFound = "" Then
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1).Value = arrColumnList(x)
            End With
            sLastFound = arrColumnList(x)
        Else
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                Dim rCheck As Range
                Set rCheck = .Rows(1).Find(sLastFound, lookat:=xlWhole)
                rCheck.EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlShiftRight
                rCheck.Offset(, -1).Value = arrColumnList(x)
                sLastFound = arrColumnList(x)
            End With
        End If

    End If

Next

End Sub
```